# How Do I Debug Not Being Able to Connect a Bluetooth Mouse?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, bluetooth

I am running 10.6 and cannot get any bluetooth mouse connected on my macbook pro.  I've tried both my mightly mouse and a proclick band.  My bluetooth is enabled (i also set it to be discoverable) and on each mouse, i've hit the button on the device to connect then select "setup bluetooth device" from the bluetooth menu, but it never finds either device.

I've used the mighty mouse for a year or two and its worked great.  I think this happened post snow leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to 10.6.1 fixed the issue.